# Is there a good way to deal with Option[Monoid[T]] mappend operations?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monoids

If I have a Monoid[T] that has a zero and mappend, it seems to me logically that the result of

```
implicit myMonoid: Monoid[T] = ...

val x: T = thing() 
val y: Option[T] = none[T]
val z: Option[T] = Some(value)

val a: T = x.mappend(y)
val b: T = x.mappend(z)

val i: T = y.mappend(x)
val j: T = z.mappend(x)
```

for a and b should be identity and x.mappend(z.get) respectively.  Similarly for i and j.

What I have right now looks like:

```
def combine(a: Option[T], b: Option[T]) = {
    a match {
        case None => b
        case Some(x) => x |+| b.getOrElse(myMonoid.zero)
    }
}
```

Is there a pre-existing construct to express this, or is this mathematically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken there should be a monoid for `Option`, so simple

```
def combine[T: Monoid](a: Option[T], b: Option[T]) = a |+| b
```

should work.

Comment: Isn't that just the regular "first `Some` value" monoid, which doesn't combine `T`s?  In Haskell language OP is looking for `liftA2 mappend` -- i.e. you can use the fact that `Option` is an applicative functor or monad to lift `mappend`.  Wish I knew Scala better.

Comment: @luqui Sorry, but i don't understand what is first Some value monoid. If i'm not mistaken `Option` is a free monoid (like List, for example), it requires the actual type to be a monoid (i.e T: Monoid), so if both args are `Some` then apply `mappend` to the values

Comment: Ah - yes - of course, Option[T] does itself have a Monoid!